# Why doesn't bind work in function inside fadeIn Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 buttons in my block. When block is displayed user can only see 2 buttons, if he clicks 1 of them, the one he clicked disappears and 3d one appears. But to prevent user from pressing another button after he already pressed one and animation is going I unbinded click for those buttons and binded back inside `fadeIn('slow',function(){ ... }`. Full code of buttons event handlers:

```
$("#tab-1").click(function tab1() {
    $('#tab-2,#tab-3').unbind('click');
    $(container_selector).fadeOut('slow', function () {
        $('#home_button_content_1').fadeIn('slow');
        $('#tab-1').fadeOut('slow', function (){
            $('#tab-2,#tab-3').fadeIn('slow',function(){
                $('#tab-2').bind('click', tab2);
                $('#tab-3').bind('click', tab3);
            });
        });
    });
});

$("#tab-2").click(function tab2() {
    $('#tab-1,#tab-3').unbind('click');
    $(container_selector).fadeOut('slow', function () {
        $('#home_button_content_2').fadeIn('slow');
        $('#tab-2').fadeOut('slow', function (){
            $('#tab-1,#tab-3').fadeIn('slow',function(){
                $('#tab-1').bind('click', tab1);
                $('#tab-3').bind('click', tab3);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

For some reason bind doesn't work and I cannot click buttons again after animation is finished. I have couple ideas why, but I am not sure. Maybe I cannot give a name to function inside click() or those names are not accessible from other fucntions, but most likely what I discovered using Google Chrom debugger it doesn't get inside function in fadeIn, when I tried to use boolean flag instead of bind/unbind.

Comment: You probably mean to `unbind('click')`

Comment: Yes `unbind('click')` works, but it doesn't bind back, there is just typo, I edited.

Comment: Off topic, but what version of jQuery are you using? `bind` has been deprecated for a while; might be time to start using `on` and `off`. For this question, you can define the event handlers as functions separately from the `click`, `bind` or `unbind` functions....

Comment: version of Jquery is 1.4

Comment: do you have your code in jsfiddle with HTML